# Under what conditions does [for any $x\in X$, $F(x,-): Y\to Z$ is continuous] imply [$F(x,y): X\times Y \to Z$ is continuous]?

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory, product-space

Let $X,Y,Z$ be topological spaces and $F(x,y): X\times Y \to Z$ be mapping.

Under what conditions does [for any $x\in X$, $F(x,-): Y\to Z$ is continuous] imply [$F(x,y): X\times Y \to Z$ is continuous]?

I know when X is discrete space, it holds. However when X is $[0,1]$, it does not hold.

Comment: Without any constraint on a continuity relative to $x$ you will not get anything besides the discrete topology.. $F(x,\_)$ and $F(x',\_)$ could be completely different even with $x'$ as close as you want...

Comment: Though not answering your (perhaps too vague) question, this might interest you: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Compact+open+topology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The least you need is that $F(-,y)$ is continuous for every $y$, but even that is not enough.

There are some cases in which continuity in each variable implies continuity, e.g. when $X$ and $Y$ are vector spaces and $F$ is a bilinear map or when $F = 0$ on a dense subset of $X\times Y$. Most of these examples use **Baire theorem**, which is something I think you'd want to check out.

In general it is a difficult question to determine when a coordinate-wise continuous function (also called "separately continuous" or "separate continuity") is continuous, as far as I know there is no simple condition for that. But you can look for example at this question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/440925/separate-continuity-implies-joint-continuity

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which I really  wanted. I will try to understand the example you recommended.